# (Embedded) C: void function() or #define for low level register handling

Tags: c, function, embedded, styles

I am looking for an answer regarding coding style for embedded software. My question is that I need to create an abstract layer to handle low lever registers operation.

There are two potential approaches, one of them is #define based and the second one is function-based.

In the first approach, I am creating simple functions, which will handle the register operation. In this example, I am setting up one microcontroller port to low state.

```c
static void breakLockNr_3()
{
    LATDbits.RD2 = 0;
}
```

In the second approach, I can use #defines to define the same operation:

At the beginning of the file:

```c
#define BREAK_LOCK_NR_3 LATDbits.RD2
#define BREAK_LOCK_NR_3_LOW 0
```

Later on in the code:

```c
BREAK_LOCK_NR_3 = BREAK_LOCK_NR_3_LOW
```

In your opinion what method is more clear to use and better for the code cleaners, speed and memory optimisation?

Comment: This is very opinion based. anyway... this seems wrong to me: `BREAK_LOCK_NR_3 = BREAK_LOCK_NR_3_LOW`. I would expect it to be `BREAK_LOCK_NR_3 = LOW` or perhaps `LOCK_NR_3 = BREAK`

Comment: I think the #define approach may be better performance-wise since your function approach results in a function call if you don't inline it which is not necessary imho. If you want to go for the function one I'd suggest you inline it

Comment: @Trickzter static functions are implicit inline and your compiler will inline a one-liner on any reasonable optimization level.

Comment: @Trickzter The compiler is likely to inline the function call in any case

Comment: Oh alright then thanks for the info!

Comment: @4386427 I don't agree, it is common practice to prefix bit values with the register names.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Like `LATDBITS_...` I think not

Comment: If you need to abstract a register access locally to one translation unit, that in itself suggests something fundamentally wrong with your approach. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Low level register access should be hidden by whole functions that does something meaningful beyond just a single register write. That is, a proper HAL and not some weird "simplify C because the poor programmers can't read it" abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the compiler with right optimizations, it is very likely that the function will be converted to an inlined function. In this case, there is no performance hit in terms of speed or text segment space. Try and see if your compiler is optimizing this. Otherwise you can explicitly define the function as inlined.

Whether a function or macro is appropriate depends on the application at hand, and several other design decisions. In general, functions would be more maintainable compared to macros. So macro should used with care.

For a more detailed discussion about why macros should be avoided, see [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/PRE00-C.+Prefer+inline+or+static+functions+to+function-like+macros)

Comment: Why do you think that this sort of one-line function will be more maintainable than a macro? Can you explain that?

Comment: Macros work by text processing during pre-processing steps. You can screw up things if they are not used properly. Macros cant be debugged as well. See [this] (https://pmihaylov.com/macros-in-c/) for a detailed discussion on this. Given that there is no overhead in using an inline function over a macro, functions are preferable over macros. But if there is a overhead of using such functions over macro (due to compiler limitations), then macro may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare fairly, your macro should be something like:

```
#define BREAK_LOCK_NB_3()   (LATDbits.RD2 = 0)
```

Otherwise the level of abstraction is not the same, as in the second example you are not really abstracting the hardware.

I agree with what has been said about the performance being identical in both cases.

However what is much more important and what you should focus on, is the way to handle registers. Usually you set or clear one bit and not the whole register for example, using a mask and so on.

Comment: But, in this case, I am defining a function-like macro. Which, I think it was quite common in C 90, where the inline function wasn't yet implemented.

Comment: Yes. If you're calling this function/macro many times, it's much better, in case your processor evolves, or if you find out you have to set 2 bits instead of one, etc...

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers indicate it is now considered to be a good practice to leverage the type system of C as much as possible. So in general everything-with-type > pre-processor-macros. In your case I would prefer function additionally annotated with 'inline'. I recommend these fairly recent links on the topic: [link1](https://betterembsw.blogspot.com/2017/07/dont-use-macros-for-min-and-max.html) [link2](https://betterembsw.blogspot.com/2017/05/define-vs-const.html) [link3](https://youtu.be/3VtGCPIoBfs?t=3128)

Answer (score -2):

The second approach is preferable because it takes less time as compared to function execution(First approach) because it will remove macro with actual value at pre-processing time. And it will make easy to understand the code.

Comment: Sorry, but that is wrong. The function is declared as static and that means it is implicit inline and your compiler will inline it. The emitted binary will be equivalent.

Comment: @user6556709 Any sources on that? I didn't hear about such behaviour and if that really exists I want to improve my knowledge.

Comment: @itachi Checkout https://godbolt.org/ and use different -O levels, i.e. -O0, -O1, -O2, ... and you'll see that inlining will happen - except for -O0

Comment: @4386427 Sure I can disassemble an executable and see what's beneath, but I wanted to know whether that behaviour is standardised. You know, compilers differ, if it's a feature of a compiler A it doesn't mean a compiler B would do the same. In that case it's good to mark the function as `inline` explicitly, to avoid possible misunderstandings. Still, `inline` is just a hint for a compiler, it's not obliged to inline the functions actually.

Comment: @itachi No optimization is standardized. But since all common compiler including most specialized embedded compilers do it like this you can assume it will be done this way. If you find a compiler which behaves different let me know. (It would be legal to behave different but inlining is one of the cheapest optimization and therefore even implement in very primitive compilers.)

Comment: @user6556709 Okay, so it's some kind of a "well known" operation. I can go with that, I'm just afraid of trusting blindly. I trusted once that operators' precedence is the same among C compilers, but I stumbled upon a compiler that needed extra parentheses for my equation to work correctly. Anyway, thanks for your time, I'm wiser now :).

Comment: @itachi You should be able to trust that operator precedence is the same for all valid C compilers. Operator precedence is part of the standard. So seeing two compilers doing it differently would mean that (at least) one of them had a bug... With respect to inline/optimization and what the standard syas, I guess the comment from user6556709 covers it

Comment: Historically, embedded compilers were notoriously bad at inlining. This isn't the case any longer. But always disassemble to be sure.